# Django running queries against different timezone

Tags: python, mysql, django

We have a Django/MYSQL application where the row_create, row_update columns are stored in UTC format.

It works fine but now my issue is to run the reports based on the timezone user picks. He could either pick pacific time/utc time or est time.

There are 20 - 30 reports that are generated.

How can I change my SQL queries to run against different timezones?

Comment: If all of entries are stored in UTC, you can convert them to the timezone picked by the user. If you paste the current code for your query, I can show you

Comment: select count(*) as count, concat(dt, ' - ', dt + INTERVAL 6 DAY) as week from
   (select date(row_create_ts) as dt from tickets where valid_flag = 'Y') x
   group by week(dt)   ..Here is one of the query, if the user picks EST then row_create_ts should be in on EST